# Show that a subset of a group is also a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a finite nonempty subset of $G$. Show that $H$ is also a subgroup if and only if $HH = H$.

I tried a couple of approaches but I'm having troubles working through them. What would be an elegant way of doing this problem?

Comment: finite groups are simpler than infinite groups, because for any element $a$, its inverse is given by one of its powers, i.e. $a^{-1} = a^k$ for some $k$

Answer (score 1):

A subset $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup if

1. $H$ contains the identity.
2. $H$ is closed under multiplication, i.e., $h,h'\in H\implies hh'\in H$.
3. $H$ is closed under taking inverses, i.e., $h\in H\implies h^{-1}\in H$.
4. Multiplication in $H$ is associative.

Condition 4 is automatically satisfied (why?). Conditions 2 and 3 imply condition 1 (why?). If $H$ is finite, condition 2 implies condition 3 (why?). $HH=H$ implies condition 2 (why?).

Comment: I like your way to answer the question without giving the solution at all.

Comment: I'm glad it helps!